# Varnish has broken php sessions

Tags: cache, varnish

I have a big project and we decided to inject varnish cache. After many edits we inject it to live server. Everything were OK, but after about 8 hours users became to complain that they login under their email pass and get into another user!

We decided to remove all session cache and restart varnish and nginx, but sometimes users continue to complain.

So the question: how could varnish break php sessions? How this situation could be?

My varnish config:

```
vcl 4.0;

acl invalidators {
    "localhost";
    "127.0.0.1";
}



backend modniyostrov {
    .host = "example-site.com";
    .port = "8080";

}

sub vcl_recv {

        if (req.method == "POST") {
            return (pass);
        }

        if (req.url ~ "/administration/?.*" ||
            req.url ~ "/app_dev.php/?.*" ||
            req.url ~ "/account/?.*" ||
            req.url ~ "/cart/?.*" ||
            req.url ~ "/currency/?.*" ||
            req.url ~ "/login_check/?.*" ||
            req.url ~ "/login/?.*" 
            req.url ~ "/logout/?.*" 

         ) {
              return (pass);
         } 

        if (req.http.Cookie) {
            set req.http.Cookie = ";" + req.http.Cookie;
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "; +", ";");
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";(ProductsViewMode|PHPSESSID|currency|APP_REMEMBER_ME|recentViews|mobile)=", "; \1=");
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";[^ ][^;]*", "");
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^[; ]+|[; ]+$", "");

            if (req.http.Cookie == "") {
                unset req.http.Cookie;
            }
        }

        #all pictures cache by 15 minutes
        if (req.url ~ "^.*\.(png|jp[e]?g|gif|swf|css|js|svg)?(\?v=.*)?$") {
            unset req.http.Cookie;
    #        set req.ttl = 900s;
            return (hash);
        }

        #clear all cache content

        if (req.method == "PURGE") {
            if (!client.ip ~ invalidators) {
                return (synth(405, "Not allowed"));
            }
            return (purge);
        }

    #clear by ban system, particulary by taggs; see FOSHttpCacheBundle
       if (req.method == "BAN") {

        if (!client.ip ~ invalidators) {
            return (synth(405, "Not allowed"));
        }

        # find
        if (req.http.X-Cache-Tags) {
            ban("obj.http.X-Host ~ " + req.http.X-Host
                + " && obj.http.X-Url ~ " + req.http.X-Url
                + " && obj.http.content-type ~ " + req.http.X-Content-Type
                + " && obj.http.X-Cache-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Cache-Tags
            );
        } else {
            ban("obj.http.X-Host ~ " + req.http.X-Host
                + " && obj.http.X-Url ~ " + req.http.X-Url
                + " && obj.http.content-type ~ " + req.http.X-Content-Type
            );
        }

        return (synth(200, "Banned"));
    }

    # Add a Surrogate-Capability header to announce ESI support.
#    set req.http.Surrogate-Capability = "abc=ESI/1.0";


    return (hash);
}

    sub vcl_hash {

        #unset req.http.Cookie;

        set req.http.X-Have-To-Hash = ";" + req.http.Cookie;
        set req.http.X-Have-To-Hash = regsuball(req.http.X-Have-To-Hash, "; +", ";");
        set req.http.X-Have-To-Hash = regsuball(req.http.X-Have-To-Hash, ";(ProductsViewMode|currency|recentViews|mobile)=", "; \1=");
        set req.http.X-Have-To-Hash = regsuball(req.http.X-Have-To-Hash, ";[^ ][^;]*", "");
        set req.http.X-Have-To-Hash = regsuball(req.http.X-Have-To-Hash, "^[; ]+|[; ]+$", "");

        if (req.http.Cookie ~ "APP_REMEMBER_ME") {
            set req.http.X-Have-User = "true";
        } else {
            set req.http.X-Have-User = "false";
        }

        hash_data(req.url);
        hash_data(req.http.host);
        hash_data(req.http.X-Have-To-Hash);
        hash_data(req.http.X-Have-User);

        return (lookup);

    }


    sub vcl_backend_response {

        #for ban some objects
        set beresp.http.X-Url = bereq.url;
        set beresp.http.X-Host = bereq.http.host;

        if (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private" ||
            beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache" ||
            beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-store"
        ) {
            set beresp.ttl = 1h;
    #        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
            unset beresp.http.Cache-Control;
        }

        if (beresp.http.X-Url ~ "^.*\.(png|jp[e]?g|gif|swf|css|js|svg)?(\?v=.*)?$") {
            set beresp.ttl = 24h;
        }

        if (beresp.status == 502 || beresp.status == 404 || beresp.http.X-Cache-Debug) {
            set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        }

    return (deliver);
    }


    # Check for ESI acknowledgement and remove Surrogate-Control header
#    if (beresp.http.Surrogate-Control ~ "ESI/1.0") {
#        unset beresp.http.Surrogate-Control;
#        set beresp.do_esi = true;
#    }


#}

sub vcl_deliver {

#     if (!resp.http.X-Cache-Debug) {
        # Remove ban-lurker friendly custom headers when delivering to client
       # unset resp.http.X-Url;
       # unset resp.http.X-Host;
       # unset resp.http.X-Cache-Tags;
#    } else {
        if (resp.http.X-Varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
#            set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
        }

#    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've made session content cacheable:

```
if (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private" ||
        beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache" ||
        beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-store"
    ) {
        set beresp.ttl = 1h;
#        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        unset beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }
```

Given that this was not obvious to you, I think you're strategy of using Varnish is the wrong decision.